# a.s. convergence of positive random variables with equality to zero condition

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose we have $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ iid. Suppose we have functions $a$ and $b$ such that for all $n$

$$
\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na(X_i)b(X_i) \geq 0
$$

and $\bar{X}_n = 0 \implies a(X_i) = 0$ a.s. Then by the SLLN $\bar{X}_n \to_{a.s.} \mu = \mathbb{E}[a(X_i)b(X_i)]$. Is it true that $\mu = 0$ implies $a(X_i) = 0$ a.s.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\overline {X_1} \geq 0$ implies $a(X_1)b(X_1) \geq 0$. So, $\mu=0$ implies $a(X_1)b(X_1) = 0$ a.s. and  $a(X_i)b(X_i) = 0$ a.s. for each $i$. Hence, $\overline {X_n} = 0$ a.s. which implies $a(X_i) =0$ a.s.